# When should a question be closed?

Tags: support

I just received the power to cast close votes, so I wanted to test it out on [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11324/when-is-one-piece-chapter-750-coming-out). It's a question where OP asks for the release date of a particular chapter, which was due the next day after a two week break. Since that day has passed and the chapter has been released, to me it felt like this question could be closed.

Before I would do so, I first wanted to verify what good reasons to closing a question would be.

Comment: Have you clicked on the "close" button on any post yet? It brings up a dialog box with a number of close reasons, one of which you have to select before your close vote is actually cast. Take a look through them - most of them are pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, congratulations on your close privileges! I see that it's your first!

Closing is done when a question cannot be answered because it is too broad, unclear or primarily opinion based, or because it is off-topic on the site or was already asked (a duplicate).

If a question does not fit any of the above criteria it probably shouldn't be closed.

The above question can indeed be answered. The answer is "It has already come out, after OP was on a 2 week hiatus". So that specific question should not be closed. It should be answered (and it was).

I protected this question a couple minutes before you asked this question in order to stop people from adding pointless answers.

Comment: What about the number of votes? It looks like I only have 24 (same goes for flags). You or senshin probably go through these at a fast pace. Do they replenish? Or is this a matter of reputation?

Comment: They replenish daily, and you get more as you accumulate more reputation.

Comment: @PeterRaeves You get a prize if you somehow manage to find 24 questions that need closing in one day. :P

Comment: A price? :D *starts looking right away*

Comment: what if the reason selected to close is not quiet reasonable and other member agree on that. what will happen ?